# How can I implode this array into a url string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, url, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$aSample = [
   'productName' => [
        'sample',
        'sample2'
    ],

   'productNumber' => [
        'numberOne',
        'numberTwo'
    ]
];
```

How can I make this array look like this one:

```
productName=sample,sample2&productNumber=numberOne,numberTwo
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: I just want to show it first in a dd()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
$aSample = [
    'productName' => [
         'sample',
         'sample2'
     ],

    'productNumber' => [
         'numberOne',
         'numberTwo'
     ]
 ];

 $array = [];
 foreach($aSample as $key=>$item) {

    $arr = $key.'='.implode(',',$item);


    array_push($array,$arr);

}
echo implode('&',$array);
```